# How can I install this nvidia-x11-drv-340xx-340.106-1 package?

Tags: server, centos, nvidia, rpm

I tried to install this rpm software on my CentOS server:

```
[root@test software]# rpm -ivh nvidia-x11-drv-340xx-340.106-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
nvidia-340xx-kmod = 340.106 is needed by nvidia-x11-drv-340xx-340.106-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

Here to say I need this nvidia-340xx-kmod package before installing nvidia-x11-drv-340xx-340.106-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.rpm package.

I try to go to another machine that can connect to the internet to view the rpm package that this nvidia-340xx-kmod package needs, and then I will download it and install:

```
yum install kmod-nvidia-340xx
```

But the dependency of the kmod-nvidia-340xx package is the nvidia-x11-drv-340xx-340.106-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.rpm package that I just wanted to install.

```
Dependencies Resolved

=================================================================================================
 Package                      Arch           Version                        Repository      Size
=================================================================================================
Installing:
 kmod-nvidia-340xx            x86_64         340.106-1.el7_4.elrepo         elrepo         4.9 M
Installing for dependencies:
 nvidia-x11-drv-340xx         x86_64         340.106-1.el7.elrepo           elrepo          36 M

Transaction Summary
```

As you see, here is a yum endless loop.

It should be noted that this CentOS server cannot connect to the Internet for some safety reasons.

Then this server can't mount a local source image, because the server room is far from my office room and I don't want to go to that room to use an external storage device to create a local source image, then the server's free space is not enough to save a centos image, free space less than 1G(forgive me this strange problem).

So my question is, I tried to install this package, but the lack of installation process prompts the lack of this package as a dependency.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they depend on each other, so you need them both installed at the same time. `sudo yum localinstall *.rpm` from the directory they're copied to should work.

Comment: Did it work? If so, an upvote and a check would be helpful. If not, what was the error?